# Schema is not flat - cannot save to selected destination (bigquery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while. I have call a query and it showed that schema is not flat when I am trying to save on google drive. I have tried unnesting, but it does not work.  This is my code:

```
SELECT h.customDimensions
FROM `database-314102.70657995.ga_sessions_20211129` ,
unnest(hits) as h
LIMIT 1000
```

It returns the following, and I think this is the problem.

[image]

Manual version:

```
Row | customDimensions.index | customDimensions.value
1   | 1                      | 1876532224.1630919937
2   | 19                     | 23848529586390596
    | 20                     | 23848735321190596
    | 21                     | 23848735321200596
```

As you can see, multiple value is stuck in the same row, and it needs to be flatten(I think). Anybody know the way to fix this problem or the root causes? If it cannnot be solved by code then is it the way the data is stored that is wrong? Help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could try to unnest the custom dimensions. It should look something like 
`SELECT customDimension.index, customDimension.value 
FROM 'dataset', UNNEST(hits) AS hit, UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) AS customDimension LIMIT 1000`

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT customDimension.*
FROM `database-314102.70657995.ga_sessions_20211129` ,
UNNEST(hits) as h, UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as customDimension
LIMIT 1000
```